# How to collect and distribute payments coming from in app purchases?

Tags: android, ios, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase

Stripe does not work with the Google and Apple payment system when it comes to purely digital transactions [in the app](https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-pay-or-in-app-purchases-for-mobile-application-payments) (e.g. tips or subscriptions for digital goods). Is there a service that can be used to collect and distribute payments that integrates with the Google/Apple payment system?

More specifically, I'm looking for a way to collect payments from users and distribute them to content creators. [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/de-es/connect) doesn't seem to be suitable for this and setting up my own payment system seems difficult.

I am really happy for any guidance...